# Only connecting points that are in order in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

This might not be a ggplot problem but how to manipulate the data frame. I have a dataset that has 4 variables, 2 are coordinates, 1 grouping variable, and another is the time.

My task is to:

1. Plot the scatter plot according to the coordinates (done)
2. Color the point with the grouping variable (done)
3. Connect the points in order according to the group.

Here is an example dataset and failed plot:

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
           order = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1),
           x = rnorm(15),
           y = rnorm(15))

data %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = factor(group)), shape = 21) +
  geom_path(aes(x=x, y = y, group = group), alpha = 0.5, arrow = arrow(angle = 30, length = unit(0.05, "inches"),
      ends = "last", type = "open"))
```

[image]
As you can see, group 1 has been correctly plotted, such that the points are connected in order (i.e. 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5). But group 2 is not. The intended plot should be the two "1"s point toward the 2, and the 2 will point toward both "3"s. And there is no connection between the "1"s and "3"s. Similarly, I do not expect there to be any line connecting group 4 as they are all in order (time) 1.

I do prefer to do it in R, but other languages that can import and outport data frames will also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_path` "connects the observations in the order in which they appear in the data". One alternative is to use `geom_segment` where you have to provide the `xend` and `yend` coordinates. The function `generate_ends` checks these for every point and generates the appropriate data (and also duplicates a point/row if there are several points this point should point at).

```r
set.seed(1)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
data <- data.frame(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
                   order = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1),
                   x = rnorm(15),
                   y = rnorm(15))

generate_ends <- function(data, ...) {
  # check for every row/point
  res <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(data)), function(row) {
    current_order <- data[row, "order", drop = TRUE]
    current_row <- data[row, ]
    # check if there is a point with a higher order
    if ((current_order + 1) %in% data[, "order", drop = TRUE]) {
      # get the coordinates from all points with higher order
      higher_order_coordinates <- data[data[, "order", drop = TRUE] %in% (current_order + 1), c("x", "y")]
      # use these coordinates as xend/yend for the current point
      current_row <- current_row[rep(1, nrow(higher_order_coordinates)), ]
      current_row <- current_row %>% 
        mutate(xend = higher_order_coordinates[, "x", drop = TRUE],
               yend = higher_order_coordinates[, "y", drop = TRUE])
    } else {
      # if there is no higher order, this point doesn't have a connection
      current_row <- current_row %>% 
        mutate(xend = NA,
               yend = NA)
    }
    current_row
  })
  bind_rows(res)
}

data_new <- data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  group_modify(generate_ends)

data_new %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = factor(group)), shape = 21) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend, group = group), alpha = 0.5, arrow = arrow(angle = 30, length = unit(0.05, "inches"),
                                                                       ends = "last", type = "open"))
#> Warning: Removed 7 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it is my bad that the toy example did not include some extreme cases. I wonder if there is any more general solution that can be applied to the scenario that there are missing levels of "order" (i.e. that may be 1 -->3 -->5, but they were still increasing). I initial intuition is to modify if ```((current_order + 1) %in% data[, "order", drop = TRUE])```. Otherwise, I believe it can be done with a new column having a pseudo-rank. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: yes, you would need to modify this, you could e.g. check if there is any point with a higher order, my first idea is `if (max(data[, "order", drop = TRUE]) > current_order)`